# Dynamic CRM -- Annotation(Note) -- IsDocument

Tags: dynamic, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I have an issue where the `IsDocument` field is always becoming true regardless of whether I set it to true or false

SDK:icrosoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Dynamics
Version:1.0.23

Here is my create code

```
 Guid noteId = await this.crmService.CreateAsync( // CreateAsync is provided by sdk
                new Annotation
                {
                    ObjectId = existingEodCase.Entities.First().ToEntityReference(),
                    Subject = request.Title,
                    NoteText = request.Description,
                    FileName = request.FileName,
                    DocumentBody = string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.FileName) ? null : request.FileData,
                    MimeType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.FileName) ? null : MimeTypes.GetMimeType(request.FileName!),
                    IsDocument = false // force to set to false
                });
```

When I get

```
// get
            var eodCaseNotesQuery = new QueryExpression(Annotation.EntityLogicalName);

            this.BuildQueryConditions(request, ref eodCaseNotesQuery);

            var eodCaseNotes = await this.crmService.RetrieveMultipleAsync(eodCaseNotesQuery);


// BuildCondition
private void BuildQueryConditions(GetEodCaseNotesQuery request, ref QueryExpression eodCaseNotesQuery)
        {
            eodCaseNotesQuery.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(
                Annotation.Fields.Id,
                Annotation.Fields.Subject,
                Annotation.Fields.NoteText,
                Annotation.Fields.IsDocument,
                Annotation.Fields.FileName,
                Annotation.Fields.DocumentBody,
                Annotation.Fields.MimeType,
                Annotation.Fields.CreatedOn,
                Annotation.Fields.CreatedBy);
            eodCaseNotesQuery.PageInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                Count = request.PageSize,
                PageNumber = request.Page,
                ReturnTotalRecordCount = request.Count
            };

            // order by createdon desc
            eodCaseNotesQuery.AddOrder(Annotation.Fields.CreatedOn, OrderType.Descending);

            eodCaseNotesQuery.Criteria.AddCondition(Annotation.Fields.ObjectId, ConditionOperator.Equal, request.EodCaseId);

            // add user link
            var userLink = eodCaseNotesQuery.AddLink(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, Annotation.Fields.CreatedBy,
                SystemUser.PrimaryIdAttribute, JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
            userLink.EntityAlias = SystemUser.EntityLogicalName;
            userLink.Columns.AddColumns(SystemUser.Fields.FullName, SystemUser.Fields.InternalEMailAddress);
        }
```

it returns IsDocument equals false

I wonder what should I do to make IsDocument equal false

Answer (score 0):

From the code given the possible reasons for IsDocument to be true is because of the FileName property.

Dataverse sets IsDocument to true when the requests has Filename, DocumentBody
or MimeType.

Please set all of them to null if the note is not an attachment. This should set the isdocument to false internally.

> You do not need to pass isdocument as it is determined internally by
> dataverse.